# How to choose different elements of a list other than the indexed element?

Tags: python

I have a list, for instance I want to select all elements other than the indexed element if I run a `for` loop on the list.

For example,

```
  var = [a,b,c,d,e]
  1st iteration: Choose b,c,d,e and ignore a
  2nd iteration: Choose a,c,d,e and ignore b
  3rd iteration: Choose a,b,d,e and ignore c
  and so on...
```

I tried using slicing but I am no able to have condition on the previous elements and how to take them.

Can someone suggest any other method?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This worked like a charm:

```
var = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]

for i in range(len(var)):
    print(var[:i] + var[i+1:])
```

Results:

```
[2, 3, 4, 5]
[1, 3, 4, 5]
[1, 2, 4, 5]
[1, 2, 3, 5]
[1, 2, 3, 4]
```

Answer (score 4):

A simple `List comprehension` using `slicing` :

```
>>> [ var[:i]+var[i+1:] for i,_ in enumerate(var) ]
```

Or

```
>>> [ var[:i]+var[i+1:] for i in range(len(var)) ]
```

#driver values :

```
IN : var = [0, 1, 2, 3, 4]
OUT : [[1, 2, 3, 4], [0, 2, 3, 4], [0, 1, 3, 4], [0, 1, 2, 4], [0, 1, 2, 3]]
```

Comment: nitpicking: Using `...for i, _ in ...` instead makes it clear*er* that `_` will not be used.

Comment: Hahaha. Yeah. Valid point. Though I am in the habit of assuming further operations involved, and so the `ele` there.

Comment: Or just iterate over the range itself?

Comment: @cᴏʟᴅsᴘᴇᴇᴅ : valid point. Too used to `enumerating` right now I guess (seems more pythonic). Missed the easier one. Thanks. Will update.

Comment: I just added the second alternative of yours and saw you had added it just before me. Can my answer stay or should it be deleted?

Comment: @trollster : its fine. Your wish, to be precise.

Answer (score 3):

This should work:

```
[[v for j,v in enumerate(var) if i!=j] for i,_ in enumerate(var)]
```

Comment: Why the `enumerate` if you're subsequently throwing the value away? Just iterate over range. Although that's already been covered.

Comment: @cᴏʟᴅsᴘᴇᴇᴅ probably the reason i got into the habit of favoring `enumerate` in situations like this is because `len` will produce an error for an iterable that isn't also a collection.

Answer (score 3):

Im just deleting and inserting the elements of list in a for loop

```
list1 = ['a','b','c','d','e']
for i in range(len(list1)):
    temp=list1[i]
    del list1[i]
    print list1
    list1.insert(i,temp)
```

**OUTPUT**

```
['b', 'c', 'd', 'e']
['a', 'c', 'd', 'e']
['a', 'b', 'd', 'e']
['a', 'b', 'c', 'e']
['a', 'b', 'c', 'd']
```

Answer (score 1):

Why not just this:

```
var = ['a','b','c','d','e']

for i in range(len(var)):
    print([x for idx, x in enumerate(var) if idx != i])
```

Which Outputs:

```
['b', 'c', 'd', 'e']
['a', 'c', 'd', 'e']
['a', 'b', 'd', 'e']
['a', 'b', 'c', 'e']
['a', 'b', 'c', 'd']
```